# How to define a Content Security Policy (CSP) that utilizes 'strict-dynamic' but includes fallback to use 'unsafe-inline'?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm implementing the CSP header on a website that needs to dynamically load some scripts due to various reasons (mostly plugins).
This is easily achieved by defining script-src using 'strict-dynamic' along with a hash/nonce for the non-dynamic scripts.

The recommendations everywhere suggest also including some high level sources/schemes and 'unsafe-inline' as fallback, in case the browser doesn't support CSPv3 and thus, doesn't support 'strict-dynamic' and dynamic loading:

```
script-src: 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-somesortofhash...' https: 'unsafe-inline';
```

This fallback method will work fine for browsers that only support CSPv1:

- 'strict-dynamic' is ignored (unrecognized).
- hash value is ignored (unrecognized).
- https: and 'unsafe-inline' are enforced.

But doesn't seem to work for CSPv2 browsers:

- 'strict-dynamic' is ignored (unrecognized).
- hash value is enforced.
- https: is enforced.
- 'unsafe-inline' is ignored (due to enforcement of hash).

How can I define a policy with proper fallback for CSPv2 browsers as well?

Comment: What the question describes is expected behavior per the requirements in the CSP spec. Regardless of whether a browser supports 'strict-dynamic' or not, if the value for a directive includes a hash, then 'unsafe-inline' is ignored. So your choice is either to not include any hashes in the directive value, or else to not include  'unsafe-inline'.

Comment: Avoiding use of hashes is meaningless since 'strict-dynamic' requires them to function. If there's no way to keep 'unsafe-inline' functionality in CSPv2 browsers, this practically makes 'strict-dynamic' useless. The whole point of the directive is to avoid 'unsafe-inline' in websites that previously had no choice but specifying it, But if there's no proper fallback...  
What I'm basically asking here is if there's some way to deal with this that I'm missing - other than sniffing the user-agent and changing the header accordingly, that is.

Comment: Unfortnuatly I'm faced with the same Problem and it seem that there is no good solution for this Problem. But I also don't understand why everybody is saying strict-nonce will make CSP more usable. As long as we have Safari (and Edge) with CSP3 only there is no real Solution!

Comment: @fwebdev Yeah I have no idea why people mention nonce as a solution for this case. I know it is safer than using hash, and that some 3rd party vendors allow you to pass one to propagate into their scripts, but they are a minority even now.

Answer (score 1):

`'strict-dynamic'` was designed mostly to work in combination with nonces. You are right - there is no perfect CSPv2 fallback when used in combination with hashes.

The uncovered case is dynamically generated inline scripts - a rare pattern, in my experience:

```js
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.innerText = 'alert(1)';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

will not work in CSPv2-compatible browsers, and the best solution in that case is to do UA sniffing and not send a policy at all.

Sourced scripts will work just fine.

On the other hand, a nonce-based policy such as:

```
script-src 'nonce-r4nd0m' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline' https:
```

will fall-back gracefully, because for the case above you can always set a nonce manually:

```js
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('nonce', 'df7Af03DRTs66pP');
s.innerText = 'alert(1)';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

More about backward compatibility and fallbacks in our presentations<sup>[1][2]</sup>.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> https://speakerdeck.com/mikispag/content-security-policy-a-successful-mess-between-hardening-and-mitigation?slide=52

<sup>[2]</sup> https://speakerdeck.com/mikispag/so-we-broke-all-csps-dot-dot-dot-you-wont-guess-what-happened-next-michele-spagnuolo-and-lukas-weichselbaum?slide=15

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly it's messy ThirdParty Scripts for Tracking that we have no controll of. The scripts are inserted by a TagManagement System to abstract it event further away. So I guess we have to deal with Browsersniffing for Safari and Edge for now.

Comment: As @fwebdev just said, the biggest issue is with third party scripts where we cannot control the nonce attribute of any dynamically loaded scripts.
Some 3rd party vendors (Zendesk for example) have added a "nonce" parameter to their widget, that will propagate to the scripts it loads, but they still seem to be a minority.

Comment: Just a reminder: this backward-compatibility problem is only in Webkit browsers and only for dynamically loaded *inline* scripts (via innerText). Dynamically loaded sourced scripts work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your policy:
`script-src: 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-somesortofhash...' https: 'unsafe-inline';`
It utilizes hash and it is not well suited with `strict-dynamic`, I would suggest using `nonce-{randomNumber}` and it could solve your issues.

I would suggest checking your policy with https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com. It would help you with all the attributes as per the version whether they are supported with the corresponding CSP version.

And if you need more help around CSP3 you could look at this:
[Firefox refuses to load any scripts with strict-dynamic set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661827/firefox-refuses-to-load-any-scripts-with-strict-dynamic-set)

Comment: Pretty much every mention of strict-dynamic specifies it can be used with **either** hash or nonce, so I'm not sure why you are saying my policy is not well suited for it...

I also don't see how using nonce would solve the described issue - when falling back to a CSP2 browser, 'unsafe-inline' will be ignored whether I use a nonce or a hash. And I need 'unsafe-inline' to be enforced because that is the only way some 3rd party scripts would work without the functionality that 'strict-dynamic' provides.